# how to return the response of an API , it shows undefined but when I try to print it , it shows exactly what I want

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, google-calendar-api

**nodejs file**

```
var result= async function meet(){
    var link= undefined;
    
    calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: 'primary', 
        conferenceDataVersion: '1', 
        resource: event 
    }, (err, temp) => {
        link = temp.data.hangoutLink; // I want to update link but it is not updating
    });

    return link;
}

console.log(result);//it shows undefined;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `https://github.com/yuhong90/node-google-calendar`?

Then insert is already returningn an promise:

```
var result= async function meet(){
    let link = await calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: 'primary', 
        conferenceDataVersion: '1', 
        resource: event 
    })
    return link.data.hangoutLink
}
```

And please... if you put `async` infront of it will return you an promise.

Promises are thenable you can use `.then()` on it to get your result

```
result().then(res => {
   console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You either look at `async` version of this function (if exists) and use it with `await` or `then` or you can wrap this call with a callback to `new Promise` like this:

```
 var link= await (new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
        calendar.events.insert(
            { calendarId: 'primary', conferenceDataVersion: '1', resource: event },
            (err, temp) => {
               if (err) {
                  reject(err)
               }
                resolve(temp.data.hangoutLink)
            })
   }));
    return link;
```

Comment: i will try, thanks for your response.